# Implement OIDC authorization code grant flow for AngularJS SPA

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, oauth2client, forgerock

I have an AngularJS application. I want to implement OIDC Authorization Code Grant flow.

I first tried with the 'Okta Auth JavaScript SDK' library to integrate my application with Okta, and the integration was successful. Now, I need to implement authentication for other providers like ForgeRock and Azure AD. I'm seeking a generic library compatible with AngularJS, incorporating modern security best practices such as the PKCE extension. Could someone please assist me in finding such a library?

Answer (score 0):

Few I have used in past:

1. **oidc-client-ts**:

   - A low-level, library for handling OpenID Connect and OAuth2. It works well with any client-side framework.
   - Provides a lot of flexibility and supports PKCE.
   - You can configure it to work with any OIDC-compliant identity provider.
   - Since it's low-level, you might have to handle some of the UI aspects and other integrations yourself.
   - [Github Repository](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts)
2. **Angular-oauth2-oidc**:

   - Tailored for Angular (though primarily newer versions, not AngularJS).
   - Makes it easy to connect any OIDC compliant authorization server.
   - Supports PKCE.
   - Depending on your AngularJS version, you might need to make a few adjustments, or consider moving to a newer Angular version.
   - [Github Repository](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc)

Comment: Thank you  @Daredevil for providing valuable input. I guess the second option is out of scope as it is angular 2 and beyond.Unfortunately  I am not aware of angular 2.  about the first option ,i.e oidc-client-ts, is there any CDN link avaialbe which I can directly include in html as we are not using npm. Also seeing 'ts' at the end , I tohught it is only compatible with typescripts !

Comment: Also can someone please help me with if there are any forgerock specfic and azure ad specfic sdk compatible with angularjs available